# Docker and Airflow - Error to init the container

Tags: docker, airflow

I got the below issue when I try to start the container where I am running airflow:

> "Incorrect remote log configuration. Please check the configuration of
> option 'host' in "

That is happening after I change the remote_logging from False to True.

My container is not starting because of this and hence I don't get to come back to the previous configuration. Is there a way I can get come back to the previous version or fix it without needing to create a new environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a container that won't keep running, but you want to start it for experimentation or modification, you can always overwrite the entrypoint config like this:

```
 docker run -it --entrypoint sh <docker-image>
```

Once you have the container shell open, you can make your modifications and then start the process that the container would have normally started, e.g. Airflow.

Comment: Hi Fritz, thank you for your answer. I actually got to fix my issue. Copying airflow.cfg locally, I fixed the file and then I run it again and the container come back to be up.